# How to order table in mysql by likes relative to their time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have simple problem, 2 mysql tables, one holds photos and the other one likes. Structure is like this:

```
table `photos` - id, name, image_id
table `likes` - id_photos, timestamp
```

Now it's trivial to order photos by their likes and get TOP 3 like this:

```
 SELECT photos.*
    , COUNT(likes.id) AS likes_count 
 FROM photos 
 LEFT JOIN likes ON photos.id = likes.id_photos 
 GROUP BY photos.id 
 ORDER BY likes_count DESC LIMIT 3;
```

But what I want to add is time relativity, meaning, that newer likes have more "weight" and even though some photos might have more likes, their are older and they order lower than photos with fewer likes but newer ones.

Is it possible to solve this problem only in MySQL ? Or with additional processing in PHP ?

Comment: Any idea what weighting function you'd like? For example, you could have a decay curve such that a like halves in value every day? Or that a like that occurred twice as long ago as another is worth half as much? But, they all have peculiarities, both good and bad. You need to choose the algorithm, then we can explain how to implement it in SQL.

Comment: You mean you need to some weight for the newer likes as per the dates they added. you need to choose some algorithm

Comment: @MatBailie The first example you have mentioned would be fine. Can I ask you for an answer with this solution please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let consider case then `likes`.`timestamp` is UNIXTIME field, so if we use SUM(timestamp) instead count the new lakes will have more weight :

```
SELECT photos.*
    , COUNT(likes.id) AS likes_count 
    , SUM(likes.timestamp) AS likes_weight 
 FROM photos 
 LEFT JOIN likes ON photos.id = likes.id_photos 
 GROUP BY photos.id 
 ORDER BY likes_weight DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Possible to use some coefficient (for example UNIX_TIMESTAMP())

```
SELECT photos.*
    , COUNT(likes.id) AS likes_count 
    , SUM(likes.timestamp)/UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS likes_weight 
 FROM photos 
 LEFT JOIN likes ON photos.id = likes.id_photos 
 GROUP BY photos.id 
 ORDER BY likes_weight DESC LIMIT 3;
```